# Unable to send test requests to backend APIs using the Azure APIM interactive portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Using the Azure portal, I’m unable to send test requests to the Echo API (and all other backend APIs).

When sending a request, I’m getting the following error:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
cache-control: private, s-maxage=0
content-length: 152
content-type: application/json
date: Tue, 12 Apr 2022 05:13:28 GMT
vary: Origin
www-authenticate: AzureApiManagementKey realm="https://AAAA.azure-api.net/echo",name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",type="header"
    {
    "statusCode": 401,
    "message": "Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API."
}
```

[image]
The request works fine when I tick the “Bypass CORS proxy” checkbox and through Postman.

I have the following global inbound CORS policy:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cors allow-credentials="true">
            <allowed-origins>
                <origin>https://AAAA.developer.azure-api.net</origin>
                <origin>https://AAAA.azure-api.net</origin>
            </allowed-origins>
            <allowed-methods preflight-result-max-age="300">
                <method>*</method>
            </allowed-methods>
            <allowed-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </allowed-headers>
            <expose-headers>
                <header>*</header>
            </expose-headers>
        </cors>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <forward-request />
    </backend>
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>
```

and the inbound ***base*** policy set on the Echo API.

I haven't expereinced this problem previously. Any ideas how I can bupass the CORS error while submitting test request in the APIM portal?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/hLqfGEP.png - Did you tried this option in the Azure APIM?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT yes that's how I got the global inbound CORS policy.

Comment: Could you please confirm that you're testing the API in APIM Service Portal (Test Menu) or in the developer portal?

Comment: Im testing from the APIM service portal, that's where the problem is.

Comment: Could you please check this option is checked in the settings menu of the Echo API! - https://i.imgur.com/Ctwf78e.png

Comment: This option is set.

Comment: Yes, that option is required! Checking the causes of the above error.

Comment: Found the cause that the _**deprecated apim portal URL is not allowing in the inbound policy origin**_ though we add the new developer portal URL and deprecated manually in the Inbound CORS Policy! - https://i.imgur.com/hqOoHou.png

Comment: Not sure I'm following, how do I get passed the problem?

Comment: Hello @ErshadNozari, could you please confirm once again where you're testing the API: A) APIM Service Portal - https://i.imgur.com/oUflpex.png B) Deprecated developer APIM portal - https://i.imgur.com/NkPbcLj.png

Comment: As already mentioned, I am testing in the APIM Service Portal and NOT through th developer portal. I have published the new (not the deprecated) developer portal, however I don't have any issues testing via the dev portal. I have updated the orginal question with a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have engaged with Microsoft on this and they are investigating the issue. As per MS initial investigation “Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps" creates a Proxy that intercepts all requests going out of Azure portal and it seem like MCAS proxy is either removing or modifying headers from the outgoing request thus causing this behaviour. Microsoft has pointed to the following document for reference: [Troubleshooting - What is cas.ms, mcas.ms, or mcas-gov.us?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/defender-cloud-apps/troubleshooting-proxy-url). MS has advised that they don’t have any ETA for the fix and that they are investigating further. Their recommendation is to check the Bypass CORS proxy option as workaround for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Access Denied
www-authenticate: AzureApiManagementKey realm="https://AAAA.azure-api.net/echo",name="Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key",type="header"
"message": "Access denied due to missing subscription key. Make sure to include subscription key when making requests to an API."
```

In this [Troubleshooting Steps of Unauthorized errors (401) while invoking APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/general/unauthorized-errors-invoke-apis#:%7E:text=Regarding%20error%20Access%20denied%20due,resource%20and%20Retrieve%20resource%20operations.) in Azure, it is mentioned clearly:

- Due to Wrong ***`Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key`***, this error occurs.

---

When you create the APIM, the Echo API is subscribed to built-in subscriptions by default.
Each subscription has two subscription keys that can be used.

[image]

**Scenario 1**:

By default, Echo API is registered to the Built-in all-access subscription so it will work perfectly until the subscription key is matched:

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

There are 2 more product subscriptions that come by default when an APIM instance is created which are Starter and Unlimited.

When the API is subscribed to that product subscriptions, then the subscription key passing in the header should match with the Original Product Subscription Keys available in the Subscriptions Menu.

[image]

Here, the Echo API is subscribed to both the products Starter and Unlimited as shown in 1st Image.
[image]
That Product Subscriptions has given with some permissions called Administrators, Developers and Guests. Any one among these should have on the user to access the APIs subscribed these products.

In the 3rd Image, you can see what APIs are subscribed to Starter Product like Echo API.

If any of the above workaround did not solve the issue, please refer the troubleshooting steps doc provided that shows all of the causes that produces this specific error **`401 Unauthorized and Missing the Subscription Key`** along with the resolution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for a comprehensive response. I've already ran through "Troubleshooting Steps of Unauthorized errors (401) while invoking APIs" and concluded that my issue is not related to Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key and/or invalid product. As mentioned in my original post the request works fine through Postman. Using the same request and Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key as in Postman I'm getting 401 in the Azure poratl, which works just fine if I tick the “Bypass CORS proxy” checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

ByPass CORS option allows the requests originating from any domain. Sometime, allowing the cross-domain access also fixes the issue. Try Azure Cross-domain policy as given below to allow access from 'any' domain (you can specify your domain too).

```
<cross-domain>
<cross-domain-policy>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain='*' headers='*' />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

For details refer MS documentation on managing cross domain access : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-cross-domain-policies

Comment: I tried by adding the folowing policy on global level, but unfortunately no luck

<policies>
    <inbound>
        <cross-domain>
            <cross-domain-policy>
                <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" />
            </cross-domain-policy>
        </cross-domain>
    </inbound>
    <backend />
    <outbound />
    <on-error />
</policies>

Comment: @ErshadNozari In your code above you have not given '*' for domain and headers (refer my code). Have you tried that?

Comment: @Pankai I do have the * set for both domain and heders elements. It's s copy and paste issue here.